# Verification error after signing code in Qt bundle (CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED, OSX)

Tags: macos, qt, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I am trying to code-sign a desktop application binary for OSX Sierra with bought COMODO certificate. 
I have a code-signing verification error `CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED` at the end of the `macdeployqt` command run:

```
$ security unlock-keychain -p "$PASSWORD" /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
$ ~/Qt5.8/5.8/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt app_name.app/ -codesign=(cat ~/keyid3) -verbose=4 -no-plugins # (1)
# (...)
Log: Finished codesigning  "app_name.app" with identity "118E862D88E30998B6C4BACB8ABCB1FBDEADBEEF"
ERROR: codesign verification error:
ERROR: "app_name.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED\nIn architecture: x86_64\n"
```

The same happens when I try to use codesign utility directly on final bundle (I am giving the same certificate ID as the XCode does):

```
+ security unlock-keychain -p "$PASSWORD" /Users/user/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
+ export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
+ CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
+ /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 118E862D88E30998B6C4BACB8ABCB1FBDEADBEEF --deep --timestamp=none '<build-path>/app_name'
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify '<build-path>/app_name' -dv
Executable=<build-path>/app_name/Contents/MacOS/app_name
Identifier=$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=19725 flags=0x0(none) hashes=611+3 location=embedded
Signature size=2359
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=2
Internal requirements count=1 size=104
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify '<build-path>/app_name'
<build-path>/app_name: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
In architecture: x86_64
+ spctl -a -v <build-path>/app_name
<build-path>/app_name/: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
```

Binary compiled and signed by XCode is accepted though by gatekeeper (I generate XCode project with CMake and then modify project properties to sign the binary - this however is not making a full bundle for me). I have used the same `codesign` command (copied from XCode's log) for signing.

I have already:

- removed and imported the certificate,
- allowed it to be used on all applications,
- checked are the permissions system default,
- checked for doubled certificates in the system.

I use qmake (Qt5.8) to create makefiles.
My bundle contents (after `make`, before `macdeploy`):

```
./Contents
./Contents/_CodeSignature
./Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
./Contents/Info.plist
./Contents/MacOS
./Contents/MacOS/app_name
./Contents/PkgInfo
./Contents/Resources
./Contents/Resources/CS_icon.icns
./Contents/Resources/empty.lproj
```

What should I do to make correct signed binary under OSX Sierra?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this:
`Info.plist=not bound`? How can I bound this file? It is already in bundle's directory. While inspecting XCode's signed binary it's `info` file is 'bounded'.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the SSL reseller I was buying the certificate from has simply not updated his website, where he was claiming the certificate works with OSX. Perhaps it has until 10.9 release AFAIR.

The only way to code-sign and use the binaries on latest MacOSes is to buy proper, targeted certificate directly from Apple (e.g. the one targeted for IPhone/iOS will not work on MacOS and vice-versa).
I wish reseller's helpdesk would know about it before I had lost the time.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your certificate in keychain is not set to "Always Trust".If "Always Trust" then set to "System Defaults".